# Paypal - what is difference between 2 developer pages?

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal

I want to use paypal in my application and I see 2 pages:
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps

[image]

and 
https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications/

[image]

be attent, that second page has 1 application in the application list, but the first page does not have any. Why and which page should be used to create test application?

Comment: The first one actually looks like the older version of the page design and everything.  They've been moving into this new design and migrating some things around.  I almost think that first page you're showing where it doesn't list your apps isn't supposed to be showing up, and it should be redirecting to the new one.  Where did you find links to that first one?

Comment: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-NET-SDK/wiki/Configuration , link inside table of Settings, clientId/clientSecret settings

Comment: I would just use the one where it's showing your apps correctly.